# How do I easily install Ion Cube on my server?

Tags: web-applications

> The 'php.ini Install Assistant' link on the installation helper PHP
>   script is provided to assist with this. Access the script from a web
>   server or a PHP cli or cgi executable and it should tell you which
>   Loader to install, which file to edit and what you need to add (it's
>   just a one line change).

http://www.ioncube.com/loader_installation.php

Okay, it seems to me that I have to access some script. Where the hell is that script is? Is it something I have to download or what?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=568689

> Alternatively, you could simply log in to cPanel through
>   WHM(http://yourdomainname.com:2086/" and then press "EasyApache" and then when you
>   rebuild it, simply enable IonCube Loader.
>
> Its really as simple as that!

Boy spend hours doing this.